# Can't seem to access the image file in my PlayerClass even though it is properly loaded

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm creating a 2D java game and ran into a nullpointer exception. Whenever I call my render in the playstate class, it throws the exception. I had previously rendered the Font file and got it to work when commenting out the player object references. The player "linkformatted.png" file is able to load after trying and catching, but the nullpointer exception stays. Changing the values didn't work.

```
public class PlayState extends GameState {

private Font font;
private Player player;

public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    font = new Font("font/ZeldaFont.png", 16, 16);
    player = new Player(new Sprite("entity/linkformatted.png"), new Vector2f(100, 100), 32);
}

public void update() {
   player.update();

}
public void input(MouseHandler mouse, KeyHandler key) {
    player.input(mouse, key);

}
public void render(Graphics2D g) {

    Sprite.drawArray(g, font, "YOU", new Vector2f(100, 100), 32, 32, 16, 0);
    player.render(g);
}
}
 
public class Sprite {

private BufferedImage SPRITESHEET = null;
private BufferedImage[][] spriteArray;
private final int TILE_SIZE = 32;
public int w;
public int h;
private int wSprite;
private int hSprite;

public Sprite(String file) {
    w = TILE_SIZE;
    h = TILE_SIZE;

    System.out.println("Loading: " + file + "...");
    SPRITESHEET = loadSprite(file);


    wSprite = SPRITESHEET.getWidth() / w;
    hSprite = SPRITESHEET.getHeight() / h;
    loadSpriteArray();

}

public Sprite(String file, int w, int h) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    System.out.println("Loading: " + file + "...");
    SPRITESHEET = loadSprite(file);

    wSprite = SPRITESHEET.getWidth() / w;
    hSprite = SPRITESHEET.getHeight() / h;
    loadSpriteArray();
}

public void setSize(int width, int height) {
    setWidth(width);
    setHeight(height);
}

public void setWidth(int i) {
    w = i;
    wSprite = SPRITESHEET.getWidth() / w;
}

public void setHeight(int i) {
    h = i;
    hSprite = SPRITESHEET.getHeight() / h;

}

public int getWidth() {
    return w;
}
public int getHeight() {
    return h;
}

private BufferedImage loadSprite(String file) {
    BufferedImage sprite = null;
    try {
        sprite = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: could not load file: " + file);
    }
    return sprite;
}

public void loadSpriteArray() {
    spriteArray = new BufferedImage[wSprite][hSprite];

    for(int x = 0; x < wSprite; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < hSprite; y++) {
            spriteArray[x][y] = getSprite(x, y);
        }
    }
}

public BufferedImage getSpriteSheet() {
    return SPRITESHEET;
}

public BufferedImage getSprite(int x, int y) {
    return SPRITESHEET.getSubimage(x * w, y * h, w, h);
}

public BufferedImage[] getSpriteArray(int i) {
    return spriteArray[i];
}

public BufferedImage[][] getSpriteArray2(int i) {
    return spriteArray;
}

public static void drawArray(Graphics2D g, ArrayList<BufferedImage> img, Vector2f pos, int width, int height, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
    float x = pos.x;
    float y = pos.y;

    for(int i = 0; i < img.size(); i++) {
        if(img.get(i) != null) {
            g.drawImage(img.get(i), (int) x, (int) y, width, height, null);

        }
        x += xOffset;
        y += yOffset;
    }
}

public static void drawArray(Graphics2D g, Font f, String word, Vector2f pos, int width, int height, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
    float x = pos.x;
    float y = pos.y;

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++ ) {
        if(word.charAt(i) != 32); // the space
        g.drawImage(f.getFont(word.charAt(i)), (int) x, (int) y, width, height, null);
    
        x += xOffset;
        y += yOffset;
    }
   

}


   }

   public class Animation {

private BufferedImage[] frames;
private int currentFrame;
private int numFrames;

private int count;
private int delay;

private int timesPlayed;

public Animation(BufferedImage[] frames) {
    timesPlayed = 0;
    setFrames(frames);

}

public Animation() {
    timesPlayed = 0;
}
public void setFrames(BufferedImage[] frames) {
    frames = frames;
    currentFrame = 0;
    timesPlayed = 0;
    delay = 2;
    numFrames = frames.length;
}

public void setDelay(int i) { delay = i;}
public void setFrame(int i) { currentFrame = i;}
public void setNumFrames(int i) { numFrames = i;}

public void update() {
    if(delay == -1) return;

    count++;

    if(count == delay) {
        currentFrame++;
        count = 0;
    }
    if(currentFrame == numFrames) {
        currentFrame = 0;
        timesPlayed++;
    }
}

public int getDelay() {
    return delay;
}
public int getFrame() {
    return currentFrame;
}
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
public BufferedImage getImage() {
    return frames[currentFrame];
}
public boolean hasPlayedOnce() {
    return timesPlayed > 0;
}
public boolean hasPlayed(int i) {
    return timesPlayed == i;
}

}
   public class Player extends Entity {

    public Player(Sprite sprite, Vector2f origin, int size) {
        super(sprite, origin, size);
    }

    public void move() {
    if(up) {
        dy -= acc;
        if(dy < -maxSpeed) {
            dy = -maxSpeed;
        }
    } else {
        if(dy < 0) {
            dy += deacc;
            if(dy > 0) {
                dy = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(down) {
        dy += acc;
        if(dy < maxSpeed) {
            dy = maxSpeed;
        }
    } else {
        if(dy > 0) {
            dy -= deacc;
            if(dy < 0) {
                dy = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(left) {
        dx -= acc;
        if(dx < -maxSpeed) {
            dy = -maxSpeed;
        }
    } else {
        if(dx < 0) {
            dx += deacc;
            if(dx > 0) {
                dx = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(right) {
        dx += acc;
        if(dx > maxSpeed) {
            dy = maxSpeed;
        }
    } else {
        if(dx > 0) {
            dx -= deacc;
            if(dx < 0) {
                dx = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}

public void update() {
    super.update();
    move();
    pos.x = dx;
    pos.y = dy;
}

@Override
public void render(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(ani.getImage(), (int) (pos.x), (int) (pos.y), size, size, null);

}

public void input(MouseHandler mouse, KeyHandler key) {

    if(key.up.down) {
        up = true;
    } else {
        up = false;
    }
    if(key.down.down) {
        down = true;
    } else {
        down = false;
    }
    if(key.left.down) {
        left = true;
    } else {
        left = false;
    }
    if(key.right.down) {
        right = true;
    } else {
        right = false;
    }
    if(key.attack.down) {
        attack = true;
    } else {
        attack = false;
    }
}

}
```

Here is what is printed:

```
Loading: entity/linkformatted.png...
Exception in thread "GameThread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.zwellis.game.graphics.Animation.getImage(Animation.java:62)
at com.zwellis.game.entity.Player.render(Player.java:82)
at com.zwellis.game.states.PlayState.render(PlayState.java:34)
at com.zwellis.game.states.GameStateManager.render(GameStateManager.java:71)
at com.zwellis.game.GamePanel.render(GamePanel.java:133)
at com.zwellis.game.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:90)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Here is what happens when I made another file to display the image:

```
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
      import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
      import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageInFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "entity/linkformatted.png";
        File file = new File(path);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(label);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is what happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
at ImageInFrame.main(ImageInFrame.java:11)
```

Here is also the github link
https://github.com/xfyktcl/ZwellisKnight.git

Comment: From what I see this is happening in either the class `Animation` or `Player`, none of which you showed the code. So unless you post a proper [mre] there's little we can do to help you

Comment: Just a guess, but use ImageIO to read the image files before you start constructing the GUI.  ImageIO will throw an error if the file location is incorrect.

Comment: @Frakcool I'm not sure how to post a minimal reproducible example since there's a lot of classes but I will add the Animation and Player classes as you said.

Comment: Create a brand new project where you only load the image and display it in the screen, from the same path as you do now, and follow Gilbert's suggestion in the comment above

Comment: `File file = new File(path);` Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.